# Overriding the area route in MVC

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a solution set up using areas with a folder structure shown below

```
Controllers

---HomeController
---SpecialController

Areas

---Admin
-----Controllers
-------AController
-------BController

---Marketing
-----Controllers
-------CController
-------DController
```

I have registered default routing as follows:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{path}/Special/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Special", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, path = UrlParameter.Optional },
    new string[] { "SomeNamespace.WebApplication.Controllers" }
);
```

I would like to configure the routing so any url with controller name 'Special' routes to the root special controller regardless of whether {path} is an area name or not. e.g.

```
/AnyTextDoesntMatter/Special/Index/1
/Admin/Special/Index/1
/Marketing/Special/Index/1    //these should all route to the root special controller
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please show the rest of your registered routes?  It's important to remember that the order of your mappings is important.  The first route that matches will be the one selected.

Also - Typically in Global.asax.cs => Application_Start the routes for areas are registered before routes for the main application.  If this is the case in your application, then you will need to add a route mapping for this special controller in your area-specific registrations.

Example Global.Asax.cs

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}
```

Comment: Didn't realise the ordering on the global was crucial. I registered the default root first and it is used first